# Set-ItemProperty physicalPath

Tags: powershell, iis-8, remote-execution

Remote execution for setting `physicalPath` is erroring with the following message:

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.

What is wrong with the following?

```bsh
$site    = Read-Host "What is the name of the virtual?"
$newpath = Read-Host "What is the NEW PATH of the new site?"

$ScriptBlockContent = {
    $site = $args[0],
    $newpath = $args[0]
    (Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\Sites\ABC_LIVE\$site -Name "physicalPath" -Value "$newpath")
}

# Add the IIS PowerShell Module
Import-Module WebAdministration 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName DEVSERVERNAME -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent -ArgumentList $site,$newpath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the module *inside* the scriptblock (the module must be installed on the remote host). Also, both variables in the scriptblock are assigned the same argument (`$args[0]`), and the first assignment has a spurious trailing comma.

Use a `Param()` block instead of individual variable assignments, and remove the pointless parentheses around `Set-ItemProperty`.

```
$ScriptBlockContent = {
    Param($site, $newpath)
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\\Sites\ABC_LIVE\$site -Name "physicalPath" -Value $newpath
}
```